Can nginx module ngx_http_sub_module return http code 404?
I had a nginx reverse proxy, and backend are plain html content. I want to know can this happen?
First, using ngx_http_sub_module or something else to filter content in html file. Such as if abc.com in html, nginx filter and return abc.net
Secode, can any module do the same thing but return a 404? (if found abc.com, and return a http 404)
I search the docs of nginx, seems 1 can do, but I didn't found any module can do the second?
Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
